# jQuery: fadeToggle() and checkboxes

Tags: jquery, checkbox

Here's the problem. I have a checkbox and when I select it an image should appear, so the div element is initially hidden. It just wouldn't work. It works when the div is visible to start with. But in this case if I select the checkbox the image will disapper and when I unselect the checkbox the image will apper. I want exactly the opposite. The workaround would be to have checkboxes checked when page loads, but this will not be acceptable. Checkboxes should be unchecked and images hidden when page loads.

```
<div id="pic1Div">
<img src=pic1.jpg>
<br>
This should be visible when checkbox is checked
<br>It does exactly the opposite
</div>
<form>
Show Picture <input type=checkbox name="pic1">
</form>
<script>
$(':input[name="pic1"]:first').click(function() {
$('div[ID="pic1Div"]:first').fadeToggle("slow", "linear");
});
</script>
```

[Here's the source code](http://www.bug.ee/checkbox.html)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Don't use `visibility: hidden`, `fadeToggle` works with `display:none`:

http://jsfiddle.net/mYpsF/

Comment: On a side note which I am putting in a comment since it isn't really related to the question, use `$('#pic1Div')` to select by ID.  ID is always unique so the `:first` is unneeded and the `#` is used for selecting by ID so you don't need `[ID=`.

Comment: Thank you very much. Fortunately the solution was easy. I only found out what JQuery was about an hour and half ago. I found a sample and tried to understand it. It felt intuitive, so edited it to suit my needs, hence the $('div[ID="pic1Div"]:first') line in my code.

Answer (score 1):

Just make the checkbox initially checked if the image is visible, or make the image initially hidden and the checkbox unchecked.

See an [example](http://jsfiddle.net/wvbsJ/1/) with the image hidden initially.

And an [example](http://jsfiddle.net/wvbsJ/1/) with the image shown initially.

---

On a separate note, is there a reason you're using an attribute selector to select an element by `id`, rather than an `id` selector:

`$('#pic1Div')`

And as you can only have one element with any given `id`, you won't need the `:first` pseudo-selector either.